# mySQL, PHP, Combine queries to determine how many unread messages in threads I belong

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql table `msg_to_user` like this

> `mtu_id | sender_id | receiver_id | mtu_thread | mtu_read`

I use two queries to determine

1. How many conversations I am participating (my id is 8907)

> ```
> SELECT * FROM msg_to_user
> WHERE 8907 IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
> GROUP BY mtu_thread
> ORDER BY mtu_id DESC
> ```

2. Then for each loop, in php, I query how many unread (`mtu_read = 0`) messages not sent by me exist within those conversations

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM msg_to_user
> WHERE mtu_read = 0
> AND sender_id != " . $mpage->IdNum . "
> AND mtu_thread = [the thread[$i] unique id resulted form previous query]
> ```

I'm basically wondering if there is a way to combine those queries together instead of two queries

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to count the number of unread messages. The below example uses `table as` shorthand and uses a select subquery to get the number of unread messages in the thread, not sent by the user. You may be able to optimise this query depending on your table structure.

```
SELECT 
    m.*, 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
        FROM msg_to_user mj
        WHERE mj.mtu_read = 0
        AND mj.sender_id != ".$mpage->IdNum."
        AND mj.mtu_thread = m.mtu_thread
    ) as mCount
FROM msg_to_user m
WHERE ".$mpage->IdNum." IN (m.sender_id, m.receiver_id)
GROUP BY m.mtu_thread
ORDER BY m.mtu_id DESC
```